# Is there a cleaner way to apply a function that requires multiple dataframe columns to grouped data?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, apply

Let's say I have a function 'f' that requires three arguments: one dataframe and two columns.

If I want to use 'func' on grouped data to create a new column. Here's a setup:

```
 import pandas as pd

 def f(x,y,z):
    return sum(x[y]**2) + sum(x[z]**3) - 50

 my_df = pd.DataFrame({'state':['Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','Alaska'],'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[4,5,6,7]})
```

The actual function I'm trying to apply is a lot more complicated but this example should do fine. I've been doing this:

```
x = my_df.groupby('state').apply(f,'a','b').rename('new_col')

my_df = my_df.merge(x, on = 'state', how = 'left')
```

Normally I would just use transform, but transform throws an error because it can only be used on one column at a time.

```
my_df.groupby('state').transform(f,'a','b') 

KeyError: ('a', 'occurred at index a')
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? I really wish there was a way to use apply and get a transformed result that has length equal to the original (ungrouped) dataframe.

Desired result:

```
     state  a  b  new_col
0  Alabama  1  4       15
1   Alaska  2  5      438
2  Arizona  3  6      175
3   Alaska  4  7      438
```

Answer (score 0):

if I am creating a new column that I want to pass values of columns on the same row I always use apply calling a function.
In your case you could have done

```
def f(row):
    return row["a"]**2 + row["b"]**3 - 50

my_df['new_col'] = my_df.apply(f, axis=1 )
```

you will get the same results

Comment: i think using `apply` here would be very slow since this function can all be done using vectorized operations: `df['new_col'] = np.power(df['a'], 2) + np.power(df['b'], 3) - 50`

Comment: You're skipping the 'groupby' part though. My example was bad in hindsight but your solution would not work if there was more than one row that was the same state. I'll edit the example to make it clearer.